# Populate html select combobox from two MySQL tables

Tags: html, mysql, select

I have two tables, one for admins, and one for users. I want a single html select box of both admins and users. I only want active users/admins, where that user/admin also has an entry in the foo table.
Here is my MySQL query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM users u, admins a, foo f WHERE u.active ='1' AND (a.admin_id = f.admin_id OR u.user_id = f.user_id)
```

Unfortunately, this puts out a nonsense result.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by nonsense? Please be more specific... What do you get whilst what you are expecting to get?

Comment: if you can give an example e.g. a set of data for each tables and what do you expect the outcome to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess your tables are set up like this.

```
foo (user_id, admin_id, ...)
users (user_id, active, ...)
admin (admin_id, active, ...)
```

If that is the case then apart from rethinking your database design (one table for all users with each user being assigned a user_level) you could try a `UNION`

```
SELECT users.user_id AS id
FROM foo INNER JOIN users ON foo.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.active = '1'
UNION
SELECT admins.admin_id
FROM foo INNER JOIN admins ON foo.user_id = admins.admin_id
WHERE admins.active = '1'
```